# MODX revolution: проблема в отображении в админке

Tags: modx, php

Привет! Захожу в админ-панель сайта и вижу справа от дерева ресурсов **"Could not find action file at: controllers/default/index.php"**. От чего это может быть и как это исправить? С путями вроде бы все нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Закинь папку setup в корень сайта, обнови установку, и все станет на свои места.

Comment: @mountpoint спасибо!